# How do I wrap a byte string in a BytesIO object using Python?

Tags: python, pandas, object, byte, bytesio

I'm writing a script with the Pandas library that involves reading the contents of an excel file.

The line currently looks like this:

```
test = pd.read_excel(archive_contents['spreadsheet.xlsx'])
```

The script works as intended with no issues, but I get a future warning depicting the following:

```
FutureWarning: Passing bytes to 'read_excel' is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. To read from a byte string, wrap it in a `BytesIO` object.
  test = pd.read_excel(archive_contents['spreadsheet.xlsx'])
```

In the interest of future proofing my code, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: `pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(archive_contents['spreadsheet.xlsx']))`?

Comment: So simple! Thank you very much :)

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively you could pass it a string, assuming decoding with `utf-8` is enough:

```py
test = pd.read_excel(archive_contents['spreadsheet.xlsx'].decode())
```